# XUnit Error for .Net Maui ViewModel - Microsoft.Maui.Controls not found

Tags: viewmodel, maui, xunit

I have a .Net Maui app that uses dependency injection.  In my MauiProgram.cs file, I add all of my views and viewmodels to the builder service as seen below:

```
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<About>();
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<Settings>();
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<Places>();
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<VM_MasterPage>();
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<VM_About>();
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<VM_AppSettings>();
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<HelperClass>();
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<VM_NearbyPlaces>();
```

The constructor for my viewmodel looks like this:

```
    private VM_AppSettings localAppSettings;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor for the NearbyPlaces View Model
    /// </summary>
    public VM_NearbyPlaces(VM_AppSettings globalAppSettings )
    {
        this.GBSPlaceDetails = new ObservableCollection<GBSPlaceDetail>();
        this.GBSRatings = new ObservableCollection<GBSRating>();
        this.GBSAllPlacesMapInfo = new ObservableCollection<GBSPlaceMapInfo>();

        localAppSettings = globalAppSettings;
        //appSettings = GBSServiceProvider.GetService<VM_AppSettings>();
    }
```

In the arrange section of my XUnit Test, I attempt to create a new instance of the viewmodel as shown below:

```
public class NearByPlacesTests
   {
       [Fact]
       public async void NearbyPLacesInitalizeTest()
       {
           try
           {
               //Arrage - set up the classes etc.
               var viewModelAppSettings = new VM_AppSettings(); **//I get the error here**

               //We need to load all the preferences before we attempt to test
               await viewModelAppSettings.Initialize(true);

               var viewModelNearbyPlaces = new VM_NearbyPlaces(viewModelAppSettings);


               //Act - call the functions that return the value(s) to check
               await viewModelNearbyPlaces.InitializeData();

               var placesCount = viewModelNearbyPlaces.GBSPlaceDetails.Count();

               //Assert - check the value returned from the function with expected values.  
               //Check to ensure all the expected values are loaded. 
               Assert.True(placesCount > 0, "No places were returned.");
           }
           catch (Exception ex) 
           {
               Assert.True(false, $"Error occured: {ex.Message}");
           }

       }
```

When I first ran the test, I received the error message as follows at the line indicated in the code:

```
   error could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Maui.Essentials
```

I added the following line to my test cs project file within the 'PropertyGroup' element based on another stack overflow post I read.

```
 <UseMauiEssentials>true</UseMauiEssentials>
```

Upon running the test after adding the UseMauiEssential line, I now receive the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I did some more searching for this error and did not really find anything.  Has anyone encountered this error before?  Any suggestions on how to overcome it?

UPDATE:  I did find this note in a GitHub Issue for dotnet/maui:

"Then came the problem of Commands, you know the new way of handling button taps. AND they should be placed in your VMs to bind the UI to. Trouble is, they are declared in Microsoft.Maui.Controls -  - a UI reference....

The issue seems to indicate this challange is resolved in .Net 8 Preview 2 - but I would prefer not to use a preview version in my app.

Any know work arounds / resolutions for this challenge?

Comment: Yes, this issue was fixed in the .net8 Preview 2. You can wait for the new version then update to the .net8 version.

Answer (score 0):

Use this attribute in your .csproj. Works fine to me.

```
<UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
```

Comment: do you mean in the test project .csproj file?

Comment: Yes, just below <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProjec>